# Example of symplectic manifold

Tags: differential-topology

```
I wonder why tangent bundle is not symplectic.
```

As you know, cotangent bundle is symplectic.

(1) question 1 : Is cotangent bundle isometric to tangent bundle ?

(2) question 2 : Why is not tangent bundle symplectic manifold ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tangent bundle and cotangent bundle of any manifold $M$ are always isomorphic as bundles.  (Note that it doesn't make sense to talk about isometric until a metric is chosen).

To see they are diffeomorphic, choose a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$.  Define a map $TM\rightarrow T^\ast M$ by sending $(p,v) \rightarrow g_p(v,\cdot)$.  One easily verifies this is a bundle isomorphism.

In particular, the abstract manifolds $TM$ and $T^\ast M$ are diffeomorphic.  This implies, by transport of structure, that $TM$ can always be given the structure of a symplectic manifold.  The issue is that while $T^*M$ is *canonically* a symplectic manifold, $TM$ is not - the symplectic structure inherited from $T^\ast M$ depends on the choice of $g$.

Comment: This is a great answer !